# Assigning data in link function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently building an app. My view has been minified to this for presentation purposes:

```
<div class='reviews' ng-repeat="review in reviews"> 
  <div><ratestar></ratestar></div>
</div>
```

I also have a directive that I built:

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.artist',[])
.controller('artistCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'dataFactory', '$routeParams', artistCtrl])

.directive("ratestar", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
        link: function( scope, ele, attrs ) {

            var $rateYo = $(ele).rateYo({
              rating:***VARIES ACCORDING TO REVIEW***
            });

        }
    };
});

function artistCtrl($scope, $http, $location, dataFactory, $routeParams){
  $scope.reviews = [{num_of_stars:1},...,{num_of_stars:3}]
}
```

Essentialy I want the `rating` in `rateYo({})` to be the `num_of_stars` from `$scope.reviews`. So when ng-repeat is run it takes each object from from `$scope.reviews` and assigns `num_of_stars` to `rating`. Anyone have any idea on how to tackle this? I had a feeling that adding class=$index to `<ratestar></ratestar>` might work, but it didn't.

Comment: Remove `scope: {}` (that's an empty [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)) and it will inherit the current scope which has `review` on it (ie, `scope.review`)